# trying to refresh page in django from view not working

Tags: python, django, refresh

I have developed a funcktion that deletes several entries in my django project. They are bases on marked checkbox values. When all done, I want to refresh my template page so that all premarked checkboxes diseapear. But when trying redirect and render, nothing really happens. I want to refresh the page as if I clicked refresh on the page. How do I do that?

views.py

```
def deleteMulti(request):

    g=request.GET
    checked=g.getlist('marked[]')
    dbase=g.get('dbase')

    print('delete: ',checked)
    print('dbase: ',dbase)

    #res=[Concert.objects.get(pk=l) for l in checked] 

    if dbase=='concert':
        deleted=[Concert.objects.filter(id=l).delete() for l in checked]
        res=Concert.objects.all()
        print('delete')
        response=redirect('events')

    return response
```

urls.py:

```
path('events',Events.as_view(),name='events'),
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to refresh the page as if I clicked refresh on the page.

it seems you have a button in your page that you want to perform **refresh page** action on it. actually it done by **JS** easily as

```
<button onclick="location = self.location.href;"> Refresh </button>
```

but if you want to do it by **django** you can do something like this

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect  # import
from django.urls import reverse  # import

    # other codes...
    if dbase=='concert':
        deleted=[Concert.objects.filter(id=l).delete() for l in checked]
        res=Concert.objects.all()
        print('delete')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('event'))  # redirect
```

Comment: I just edited the answer! **doesn't redirect correctly** mean it was redirecting the same page ? (may i could help, if you explain that a little bit more..)

Comment: it doesn't refresh the page. I think I have to add a function that clears the checked boxes in the template